# directed weighted graph from pandas dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, networkx

I have a pandas dataframe (lets say df) which has three columns:

```
src       dst       weight
a         b         2
c         d         7
b         a         5
d         c         1
d         a         3
a         a         4
b         b         1
```

I want to create a directed weighted graph. I have tried the following but i could not get weights into the visualisation.

```
G = nx.from_pandas_dataframe(df,source='src', target='dst', edge_attr=['weight'], create_using=nx.DiGraph())
nx.draw_circular(G, with_labels=True)
plt.show()
```

Any suggestion how to visualize weight of the edges? Moreover, I would be interested to see weights of both directions between two nodes (if bi-direction connection is present). I would also be interested to visualize nodes which are connected to themselves with a certain weight. For example, in the sample data, node 'a' is connected to node 'a' with a weight of 4, how would you visualize it as a king of closed or loop connection? I am using Networkx library.

Comment: Can you print `G.edges(data=True")? It works fine on my pc.

Comment: yes this does show weight. May be I am not visualising it right. How do I see the weight of an edge (kind of weight label) on the network plot?

Comment: you can draw it with other methods.

Comment: Don't think I have time to answer this one. Suggestion: I think you have typos in your data. Also, please make your answer clear by providing a working example with expected output. Third, edit it in your main text rather than comment.

Answer (score 2):

`graphviz` has various feature to render complex graph in various formats and even `networkx` has plugins to `graphviz`. See [here](http://graphviz.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html) for details.

Here's a simple graph generated via `graphviz` using your data. You can add many bells and whistles such as node, edge colors, fonts etc. 
You can also save directly to specific file formats including pdf.

```
from graphviz import Digraph
import pandas as pd

G = Digraph(format='jpeg')

G.attr(rankdir='LR', size='8,5')
G.attr('node', shape='circle')

df = pd.read_csv('data.txt', sep=",", engine='python')

nodelist = []
for idx, row in df.iterrows():
    node1, node2, weight = [str(i) for i in row]

    if node1 not in nodelist:
        G.node(node1)
        nodelist.append(node2)
    if node2 not in nodelist:
        G.node(node2)
        nodelist.append(node2)

    G.edge(node1,node2, label = weight)

G.render('sg', view=True)
```

[image]