# Adjusting the width of edges in a python graphviz graph

Tags: python, graphviz, pygraphviz

I am trying to visualize a transition probability matrix for a finite Markov chain using the python interface to graphviz.  I want the states of the Markov chain to be nodes in the graph, and I want the edges of the graph to have width proportional to the conditional probability of a transition between states.  I.e. I want thick edges drawn for edges with big weights and skinny ones for edges with small weights.

The discussion at ([directed weighted graph from pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48645180/directed-weighted-graph-from-pandas-dataframe/48728709#48728709))
is similar to what I want, but it would present transition probability information as textual labels rather than by edge width, which would lead to an unhelpful and difficult-to-read graph.

I am happy to consider tools other than graphviz for this task.

Here is the class I'm trying to build:

```
import graphviz
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


class MarkovViz:
    """
    Visualize the transition probability matrix of a Markov chain as a directed
    graph, where the width of an edge is proportional to the transition
    probability between two states.
    """

    def __init__(self, transition_probability_matrix=None):
        self._graph = None
        if transition_probability_matrix is not None:
            self.build_from_matrix(transition_probability_matrix)

    def build_from_matrix(self, trans, labels=None):
        """
        Args:
          trans: A pd.DataFrame or 2D np.array.  A square matrix containing the
            conditional probabability of a transition from the level
            represented by the row to the level represented by the column.
            Each row sums to 1.
          labels: A list-like sequence of labels to use for the rows and
            columns of 'trans'.  If trans is a pd.DataFrame or similar then
            this entry can be None and labels will be taken from the column
            names of 'trans'.

        Effects:
          self._graph is created as a directed graph, and populated with nodes
            and edges, with edge weights taken from 'trans'.
        """

        if labels is None and hasattr(trans, "columns"):
            labels = list(trans.columns)
            index = list(trans.index)
            if labels != index:
                raise Exception("Mismatch between index and columns of "
                                "the transition probability matrix.")
            trans = trans.values

        trans = np.array(trans)
        self._graph = graphviz.Digraph("MyGraph")

        dim = trans.shape[0]
        if trans.shape[1] != dim:
            raise Exception("Matrix must be symmetric")

        for i in range(dim):
            for j in range(dim):
                if trans[i, j] > 0:
                    self._graph.edge(labels[i], labels[j], weight=trans[i, j])

    def plot(self, ax: plt.Axes):
        self._graph.view()
```

I would initialize an example object using a data frame that looks something like

```
     foo  bar  baz
foo  0.5  0.5    0
bar  0.0  0.0    1
baz  1.0  0.0    0
```

I'm running into the following error

```
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/.../markov/markovviz.py", line 16, in __init__
    self.build_from_matrix(transition_probability_matrix)
  File "/.../markov/markovviz.py", line 53, in build_from_matrix
    self._graph.edge(labels[i], labels[j], weight=trans[i, j])
  File "/.../graphviz/dot.py", line 153, in edge
    attr_list = self._attr_list(label, attrs, _attributes)
  File "/.../graphviz/lang.py", line 139, in attr_list
    content = a_list(label, kwargs, attributes)
  File "/.../graphviz/lang.py", line 112, in a_list
    for k, v in tools.mapping_items(kwargs) if v is not None]
  File "/.../graphviz/lang.py", line 112, in <listcomp>
    for k, v in tools.mapping_items(kwargs) if v is not None]
  File ".../graphviz/lang.py", line 73, in quote
    if is_html_string(identifier) and not isinstance(identifier, NoHtml):
TypeError: cannot use a string pattern on a bytes-like object
```

which says to me that the only allowable attributes for an edge are strings or bytes.  My questions:

- Is it even possible to show the graph I'm trying to build in the python interface to graphviz?
- If so, how do I associate numeric weights with the edges?
- Once I have the weights attached to the edges, how do I draw the graph?

Comment: You've truncated the traceback. It would help if we knew what line in your code was generating that error.

Comment: @larsks, thanks.  I have updated the post to show the full traceback.

Comment: At the point this error occurs, what are the values of `labels[i]`, `labels[j]`, and `trans[i, j]`? Ideally, show the `repr()` of each of those.

Comment: ```(Pdb) labels[i]
'foo'
(Pdb) labels[j]
'foo'
(Pdb) trans[i, j]
0.5
```

Comment: That matches my assumptions from yesterday and suggests the answer below is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Your problems stems from the line:

```
    self._graph.edge(labels[i], labels[j], weight=trans[i, j])
```

The problem here is that dot attributes can only be string values, whereas looking at the rest of your code, it looks as if `trans[i, j]` will probably return a float value.

The simplest solution is probably to just call `str()`:

```
    self._graph.edge(labels[i], labels[j], weight=str(trans[i, j]))
```

Here's a test that reproduces the problem and the solution:

```
>>> import graphviz
>>> g = graphviz.Digraph()
>>> g.edge('a', 'b', weight=1.5)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/lars/.local/share/virtualenvs/python-LD_ZK5QN/lib/python3.9/site-packages/graphviz/dot.py", line 153, in edge
    attr_list = self._attr_list(label, attrs, _attributes)
  File "/home/lars/.local/share/virtualenvs/python-LD_ZK5QN/lib/python3.9/site-packages/graphviz/lang.py", line 139, in attr_list
    content = a_list(label, kwargs, attributes)
  File "/home/lars/.local/share/virtualenvs/python-LD_ZK5QN/lib/python3.9/site-packages/graphviz/lang.py", line 111, in a_list
    items = [f'{quote(k)}={quote(v)}'
  File "/home/lars/.local/share/virtualenvs/python-LD_ZK5QN/lib/python3.9/site-packages/graphviz/lang.py", line 111, in <listcomp>
    items = [f'{quote(k)}={quote(v)}'
  File "/home/lars/.local/share/virtualenvs/python-LD_ZK5QN/lib/python3.9/site-packages/graphviz/lang.py", line 73, in quote
    if is_html_string(identifier) and not isinstance(identifier, NoHtml):
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
>>> g.edge('a', 'b', weight=str(1.5))
>>> print(g)
digraph {
        a -> b [weight=1.5]
}
>>>
```

> Once I have the weights attached to the edges, how do I draw the graph?

Take a look at the `render` and `view` methods:

```
>>> help(g.render)
render(filename=None, directory=None, view=False, cleanup=False, format=None, renderer=None, formatter=None, quiet=False, quiet_view=False) method of graphviz.dot.Digraph instance
    Save the source to file and render with the Graphviz engine.
[...]
>>> help(g.view)
view(filename=None, directory=None, cleanup=False, quiet=False, quiet_view=False) method of graphviz.dot.Digraph instance
    Save the source to file, open the rendered result in a viewer.
[...]
```

Comment: Thank you.  This got me 90% of the way there.  It turns out that 'weight' is the wrong property for me to be setting.  'penwidth' is what graphviz needs to produce heavier arrows.  The value of penwidth is numeric, but it needs to be set as a string.